# Spring Post Request striping # From Value

Tags: spring, forms, http, post

I am trying to pass data via a post request into a controller but the `#` are getting stripped from the value. I've tried `HttpRequestUtil.getParametersMap(request)` and the `@RequestParam("param")` but both seem to be stripping `#`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlerReceiptSinglePost(@RequestParam("bill_to_address_line2") final String billingLine2, final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model)
{

    LOG.info(billingLine2);
}
```

when I post to this method with a form like this:

```
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
   <input name="bill_to_address_line2" value="#4"/>
</form>
```

I get this in the logs

```
INFO  [Controller] "4"
```

are there any configurations in spring that would be causing this? or anything I should check to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Even when I get the encoded data directly from the body of the request with `@RequestBody` the `#` just go missing, every other special char seems to be url encoded as expected when submitting a form. There must be some filter in spring that is pulling this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Use encoded request to support special characters on your post values
 check this blog
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest&method=setCharacterEncoding

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. And as far as I can tell all the encoding is aligned, both the client and server are using "UTF-8" and ContentType of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Try to replace hash(#) with \\# in your code. Notice the double slashes. Alternatively  you can replace # with \\u0023